# Android - Install signed apk via Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Good day.

I have an application and I recently wrote a code to make it update programatically by fetching the updated apk file on a server I host. I made the updated apk by changing the version code to version 2 and version name to 1.0.1 in the Android Manifest file. I also placed a textView in the first activity to know if it is the updated application or not. However, an issue I encountered while updating is that I get the `An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed` error when Android tries to install the downloaded apk file. Since the error is about a conflicting signature, I guessed that whenever I install an application to my device (Nexus 7) from Eclipse, the application is not signed. What I did was that I Exported a signed copy of the version 1 of the application, moved it to my Nexus 7, and installed. From that signed application version, I tried to update and I encountered no problems.

However, this process is not efficient at all because if I want to debug my application to see if data stored like the database or sharedPreferences persist between app updates, what I'll have to do is to export my app, copy to tablet, then install. This does not allow me to use logCat efficiently - as the session filter won't work. The only way for me to see my logs is via the `All Messages` category and look for my tags.

So, my main question is: Is there a way to install a signed copy of your application via Eclipse so you can still debug efficiently via LogCat?

A secondary question: What happens to the private app data like the SQLite Database and the SharedPreferences when the application upgrades versions? Are they deleted?

Comment: Application Data remains in you app after upgrades.

Comment: Okay thank you for that comment. Solved half my worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug (or run) Android will use the default store key for signing your application, and you can change it on Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build

Change your debug keystore there with custom debug keystore

Comment: For Mac OSX users. The keystore file is stored at Eclipse.app/Contents/Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its possible to install signed copy your application via Eclipse and you can still debug efficiently via LogCat.
Follow These steps.
1. Right click on your project from project list in eclipse.
2. Click Export.
3. Then select Export Android Application
4. Then select the project to export.
5. Click Next.
6. Then give the path of signing key (Keystore file). If you don't have any then create new keystore file by selecting Create new Keystore radio button on that Dialog.
7. Enter and confirm password and click Next.
8. Select Alias of Keystore file. which you have given while creating that file.
9. Enter password for that Alias and click Next.
10. Select the destination to export apk file and click finish.

It may take few minutes to build your app. Time depends on your application size.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do to export my apk file. My concern is how to install that apk to the device via Eclipse.

Comment: use adb command to install. Syntax is adb install "path of your apk file"

Comment: Or else you can change your default debug key to other signing key. So whenever your build or run your app it will build with that particular signing key. Go to window-->Preferences-->Android-->Build--> Edit the path of Default Debug Keystore